# How to solve Failed to compile error when running npm run dev?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

```
Failed to compile.
[1]
[1] ./src/index.js
[1] Module not found: Can't resolve '.components/App' in 'C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\ChatBot\client\src'`
```

I'm receiving this result when I run ...`npm run dev`

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `.components/App` looks like a typo.  Did you mean:  `./components/App` ?

Answer (score 0):

can you try `import App from './components/App'` instead  `'.components/App'`